# Upgrading Lenovo IdeaPad Z570 to 16 GB RAM

Tags: windows-7, windows, laptop, memory, lenovo-laptop

Can I upgrade a Lenovo Z570 (20095) to 12 GB or 16 GB of RAM?

As per the official specifications, it supports a max of 8 GB. Few folks over the Internet are claiming to have upgraded to 16 GB. Should I take the chance or go with the specification?

**OS:** Windows 7 Professional x64 (64-bit)

The RAM is DDR3 1333 MHz SO-DIMM 204 Pin.

P.S. I am from India.

Comment: What OS are you running?

Comment: I am using Windows7 as base OS. But I run lots of OS in virtual box, most of them are Linux. Arch, Ubuntu, Opensuse and at times Kali. My current RAM is 4GB (single module), which is full almost all the time. Laptop has 2 slots in total.

Comment: You will need to be a bit more specific on what version of Windows 7 it is.  Home Premium x32 bit?  Professional x64 bit?  That could determine if it is possible.

Comment: It's Windows-7 Professional 64 bit,  Version 6.1.7600 Build 7600

The processor is Core i5 2nd gen { Intel(R) Core(TM) i5-2430M CPU @ 2.40GHz, 2401 Mhz, 2 Core(s), 4 Logical Processor(s)}

[Intel Core i5 2430M @ 2.40GHz  Sandy Bridge 32nm Technology]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I was able to upgrade my IdeaPad Z570 to 16Gb, and have been running it for years with no issues.  I've used Windows 7, Ubuntu 14.04, Ubuntu 16.04... and some version of Fedora (that was ages ago, don't recall exactly).  I wrote about it on my blog in May 2014: [Upgrading Lenovo Ideapad Z570 to 16Gb](http://failedturing.blogspot.com/2014/05/upgraded-lenovo-ideapad-z570-to-16gb-ram.html)

Here ia a link to the exact model of Crucial memory I used: [Crucial memory on Amazon](http://amzn.to/2pddhJx), plus a [how to video on YouTube](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=TDlQAWjtw90) that I found helpful.  Some folks that commented had similar success, others had issues and had to use Samsung memory.  So your mileage may vary.  Good Luck.

Comment: This is a kickass answer, but please consider linking your video directly and the model numbers here. Your blog might go down in the future, and then this answer is useless.

Comment: fair enough, I've edited to include the links directly.

Answer (score 0):

Whether or not you can upgrade your RAM is dependent on hardware limitations and what OS you are running.

Regarding Hardware, I do not see any problems.  Although, this is a judgment call you may need to make on whether to follow Lenovo's recommendation.

**Regarding Operating Systems**

Some versions of Windows 7 have a limited amount of memory it can support.

Here is a table I found off [Microsoft's site](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa366778(v=vs.85).aspx)

[image]

**Disclaimer:** While I do not see any problems with you pushing it to 16GB, I cannot say I recommend ignoring Lenovo's documented limitation unless you are feeling adventurous.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. The issue is lenovo support is recommending only 8Gb with this laptop. I don't understand despite of having supporting hardware why won't they let me use more then 8Gb. Is there any to find Max supported RAM by my machine ?

Comment: I am not seeing any direct limitations on why you would only be able to push it to 8GB like Lenovo states.  This is where you may have to make a judgment call, unfortunately.